# CodeBlocks .exe has stopped working

Tags: c++

my .exe well compiled program stops working after run it in CodeBlocks,
It stops after typing cin>>f.name the  to the console after the choosed choice
I have a Windows 8 and i use GNU GCC compiler here is the code,maybe there is a code error , i don t know
tanks for your attention
:

```
using namespace std;
struct employee
{
string name;
int age;

};
employee employeeList[10];
class Stack
{
int pos;

public:
Stack(){};
void push(employee e)
{
    employeeList[pos] = e;
    pos++;

}
employee pop(int n)
{
    if(n = pos - 1)return employeeList[pos];
    if(n < pos - 1)
    {
        return employeeList[pos];
        for(int j =n; j < pos; j++ )
        {
            employeeList[pos] = employeeList[pos + 1];
        }

    }
    pos--;
 }
string print(int n)
{
    n = pos;
    cout<<employeeList[pos].name<<endl;

}

char menu()
{

    char choice;
    cout << "Press 1. to push an employee"<<endl;
    cout << "Press 2. to pop an employee"<<endl;
    cout << "Press 3. to show an employee"<<endl;
    cin>> choice;

    return choice;


}


};

 int main()
{
Stack s;
char input = s.menu();
int j;

do
{
    switch(input)
    {
        case '1' :{employee f; cin>>f.name; s.push(f);}break;
        case '2' :{int n; cin>>n; s.pop(n);} break;
        case '3' :{int n; cin>>n; s.print(n);}break;
    }
    j++;
}
while(j < 10);


return 0;

}
```

Comment: Do you have any information on the error that happens? Without it this is very hard for us to help you with.

Comment: i have no idea why codeblocks will crash on that but @lodo is right; you did not initialize `pos`. set a breakpoint in your `push` function and see what happens

Comment: yes that was the problem now works fine: don t crash,howether i still have some problems with some loop i think, because the program ends asking me a choice only one time

Comment: The program does end asking you a choice only one time because of the same problem as before: you didn't initialize a variable! (I'm talking about `j`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't proper initialization of instance variable "pos" of class "Stack". This means that initially it can have any value. If that value is beyond the range of your "employeeList", you are accessing an area of memory that does not belong to you. That's probably a segmentation error.